# Highlighting matched words within a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string in Javascript:

```
Smith, Dan
```

I have some Javascript to highlight the parts of that string which match an array of words (based on search input from a user). So if the user types "smith d", then my array and expected output will contain:

```
string = "Smith, Dan"
word[0] = "smith"
word[1] = "d"
output: <em>Smith</em>, <em>D</em>an
```

However this falls over when the second word is contained within the first word. So for example if the string is "Smith, Helen" then the following happens:

```
string = "Smith, Helen"
word[0] = "smith"
word[1] = "h"
output: <em>Smit<em>h</em></em>, <em>H</em>elen
```

I am using a regular expression to do the replace since there is a requirement to keep the source text case the same (so if the user types "smith", I still get "Smith" returned).

Here is my code:

```
var output = "Smith, Helen";
var arText = new Array();
arText[0] = "smith";
arText[1] = "h";
for (var iw = 0; iw < arText.length; iw++) {
    var term = arText[iw];
    var re = new RegExp('(' + term + ')', 'gi');
    output = output.replace(re, '<em>$1</em>');
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can modify this so that it ignores words which are already inside an em tag? My desired output for the code above is:

```
<em>Smith</em>, <em>H</em>elen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your search is concerned with word boundaries. I don't know all of your edge cases, but this addition to your existing code does return the output you seek. It should also apply as long as the search is concerned with line breaks.

```
var output = "Smith, Helen";
var arText = new Array();

arText[0] = "smith";
arText[1] = "h";

for (var iw = 0; iw < arText.length; iw++) {
  var term = arText[iw];
  var re = new RegExp('(\\b' + term + ')', 'gi');
  output = output.replace(re, '<em>$1</em>');
}// notice the \\b which means look for term by line break. double escape for string.
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"<em>Smith</em>, <em>H</em>elen"
```

Another more complex example

```
var output = "Smith, Helen butter";
var arText = new Array();

arText[0] = "smith";
arText[1] = "h";
arText[2] = "bu";

for (var iw = 0; iw < arText.length; iw++) {
  var term = arText[iw];
  var re = new RegExp('(\\b' + term + ')', 'gi');
  output = output.replace(re, '<em>$1</em>');
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"<em>Smith</em>, <em>H</em>elen <em>bu</em>tter"
```